# Web page monitoring with performance statisitcs, also web transactions

Tags: web-server, monitoring, zabbix, opennms

Do any of the open source monitoring applications do the following:

1. download a web page, and provide a detailed breakdown of how long it took to download the page and all its elements (images/css/javascript/etc).
2. web transaction, something that will go through a shopping cart from product page to checkout every x minutes to ensure it is working.

Would zabbix or opennms do the above?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache, then the access logs should provide some of the information you desire.  Then you can analyze the stats with something like awstats package.

Comment: I'm referring to a monitoring tool like zabbix/opennms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Zabbix can do what you are asking.  It will not tell you how long each element takes to download but more for the main page itself.  It can also perform some basic exercising of Web applications.

Web monitoring in Zabbix 1.8:
http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/web_monitoring

Web monitoring in Zabbix 2.0:
http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/web_monitoring